# How can I improve a poorly-done concrete patch in a basement slab?

Tags: basement, cement, rough-in

I had a plumber dig a trench to rough-in a bathroom in my basement. The concrete repair was done fairly poorly. It had areas that bumped up higher than original floor.  I had them come back to fix it and they used a grinder to level it.

It's now *much* better but there are still areas where the concrete patch sits *lower* than the original foundation floor.  It's very minor; maybe 1/8th of an inch in the worst places.  I'm planning on using DRIcore style subfloor (2ft x 2ft tongue + groove boards) and when I place one of those on top of some of these problematic areas, the subfloor board teeters a bit when I step over it.  So I'm concerned that the floor will not be stable once I install the subfloor boards.

Questions:

- Can I / should I use something like self-leveling cement to flatten out those areas?
- Any other products or tips to help me get a smooth, flat and straight cement floor beneath the subfloor?

Comment: Dricore has small wedges that are used to deal with minor variances in level.

Comment: "Backfill" usually refers to subsoil (or soil in general), not concrete. You shouldn't use self-leveling product, which has a very specific purpose that's not this. You should use a vinyl patch/skim coat and a wide trowel.

Comment: Or, get the contractor to do it right.